# Rewarded video ad failed to load

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

Every time when i run the code its call onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) function. I am using [codelabs example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-rewarded-video-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0).
Sorry for bad English and thanks for helping me. 
here is my code. I used many tutorial .
Is there anything I did it in the wrong way?

Or I just missed some steps?

```
public class Rewardedvideo extends AppCompatActivity implements 
RewardedVideoAdListener {
RewardedVideoAd mAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rewardedvideo);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-
3940256099942544~3347511713");

    mAd=MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(Rewardedvideo.this);
    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadrewardedvideoAd();
}
public void loadrewardedvideoAd(){
    if(!mAd.isLoaded()){
        mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",new 
AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
public void startvideo(){
    if(mAd.isLoaded()){
        mAd.show();
    }
    else {
        mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",new 
AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mAd.show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  
amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startvideo();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mAd.resume(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mAd.pause(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mAd.destroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

here is my code. I used many tutorial .
Is there anything I did it in the wrong way?

Or I just missed some steps?

Comment: More helpful would be your code of ad implementation

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Yupi thanks for your reply. I got this message even when i execute codelabs example code.

Comment: `codelabs example code` tells me nothing.

Comment: Have a look at logcat - you should see messages with an 'Ads' tag that may provide further information

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not get video source.
try again after few time